# Get Chatter Group Link with URLFOR

Tags: visualforce, chatter, bestpractice, urlfor

Would like to add a link to a chatter group to a visualforce page. Following best practices was trying to use `{!URLFOR()}` so the page doesn't break if the chatter group url format changes. However, I can't seem to find an applicable action for chatter group. Am I just missing something or did Salesforce just skip implementing this for chatter groups ...

For example to go to an account, I could do `{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View,accountId)}`.